# Выбор блоков, проверка после нажатия кнопки

Tags: javascript, html, css

Надо выбирать блоки 4 и 6, при нажатии проверить если правильно обводилось зеленым, если другие выбрал красным. Спасибо.

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%
}

.box {
  white-space: nowrap
}

.box div {
  width: 90px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div>один</div>
    <div>два</div>
    <div>три</div>
    <div>четыре</div>
    <div>пять</div>
    <div>шесть</div>
    <div>семь</div>
  </div>
</div>
<button type="button" name="button">Проверить</button>
```

Comment: Кто выбрал? Что является правильным? На наличие чего проверять  `4 && 6` ?  Другие почему красным? О чем вопрос?  На чемпионате мира по непонятным вопросам как минимум призовое место....

Comment: 4 и 6 правильные

Comment: что должно происходить по нажатию кнопки? Что проверять?

Comment: Человек выбирает блок(и), при нажатии проверить должно высветиться, то что выбрал, правильные - зеленым, неправильные - красным. Например, выбираю 1 и 4, при нажатии проверить 1 - становиться красным,а 4 - зеленым

Comment: @АндрейЗахаров, каким образом выбираются блоки?

Comment: кликом по div'у

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".container .box div");
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  divs[i].onclick = divClick;
}

function divClick() {
  // uncomment the loop if only one can be selected
  //for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  //  divs[i].classList.remove("clicked");
  //}
  this.classList.add("clicked");
}

function check() {
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    if (divs[i].classList.contains("clicked")) {
      divs[i].style.borderColor = (i == 3 || i == 5)? "#0F0" : "#F00";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%
}

.box {
  white-space: nowrap
}

.box div {
  width: 90px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black
}

.box div.clicked {
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div>один</div>
    <div>два</div>
    <div>три</div>
    <div>четыре</div>
    <div>пять</div>
    <div>шесть</div>
    <div>семь</div>
  </div>
</div>
<button type="button" name="button" onclick="check()">Проверить</button>
```

Comment: А можно выбрать несколько блоков сразу, и без correct и incorrent? Спасибо.