# Проверка classList.contains

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть `div'ы.` При нажатии на них добавляется `class="clicked".` После нажатия проверки `onclick="check();"` выводит результат в виде вычеркивания цветам красный - неправильно, зеленый - правильно. Как сделать еще вывод сообщения, если все правильные `div'ы` выбраны. В echo например, или еще как нибудь.

```
<div class="text">1</div>
<div class="text">2</div>
<div class="text">3</div>
<div class="text">4</div>
<div class="text">5</div>

 function check() {
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
      if (divs[i].classList.contains("clicked")) {
        divs[i].style.borderColor = (i == 1 || i == 2 || i == 3 )? "#0F0" : "#F00";
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Вы, случайно, не зaбыли принять ответ, который Вам дали? -   https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/866822/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8

Comment: принял, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function check() {
  var correct = 0;
  var incorrect = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    if (divs[i].classList.contains("clicked")) {
      if (i == 1 || i == 2 || i == 3) {
        divs[i].style.borderColor = "#0F0";
        correct++;
      } else {
        divs[i].style.borderColor = "#F00";
        incorrect++;
      }
    }
  }
  if (correct == 3 && incorrect == 0)
    document.getElementById("alert").textContent = "All correct things selected.";
  else
    document.getElementById("alert").textContent = "Not all correct things selected.";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, например если выберу все правильные + еще один неправильный, тогда как сделать чтобы alert не срабатывал?

Comment: И еще в <p class="alert" id="alert">ALERT</p> тут как вывести?

Comment: Спасибо еще раз, вопрос решил